# Bing Code Search not working, makes VisualStudio crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, bing

I just installed [Bing Code Search](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/02/17/introducing-bing-code-search-for-c.aspx) for Visual Studio and C#, when I start visual studio, it launches normally, but once I start typing to get the intellisense that helps you search snippets, Visual Studio stops working and shows me the famous Visual Studio has stopped working.

Update : Bing Code Search never worked for me, using normal internet connection or using proxy

What could be the cause of this ? And how do I fix this ?

Comment: Possible lack of support for Proxies in the Big Code Search?

Comment: maybe not, because i am not using any proxy and I am having the same issue first, after running again, it says "no code snippet found", seems like it fails to connect to internet

Answer (score 1):

- Goto %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions
- Peek into each of the installed extensions, you can read manifest file to check
  if it is Bing Snippet Search.
- Delete the specific extension folder
- Restart IDE. If it still does not work, repair the VS 2013 installation.

Comment: My visual studio is already working, I just disabled the extension, my problem is that I want to use that extension priperly